# Google maps api - polygon mouseover

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps API v3 and have created several polygons on the map.  I want the functionality that when the user hovers over a given area (polygon) the individual polygon changes color.  Is there any way to do this? (Later I'd like to be able to register mouse events on the given area as well). thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure this out in case anybody else has this issue..

Simply attach an event listener to the polygon object, i.e. `mouseover` and `mouseout` events.  In the listener simply invoke the `setOptions()` method on the polygon to set the desired properties.

Answer (score 2):

The current polygon object is accessible via **this**:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(yourPolygon, 'mouseover', function() {
    var currentPolygon = this;
    currentPolygon.setOptions(...)
});
```